# Why ReSharper offers a variable name with a "class" suffix?

Tags: visual-studio, variables, resharper, naming

I was wondering why R# offers a variable name with a "class" suffix? When I am creating an instance of a class, why would I put a class suffix of my instance? Can there be any reason to have a such thing:

```
BusinessClass myBusinessClass = new BusinessClass();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it just uses the class' name. So for a string it would suggest `myString` as variable name.

The question is rather: Why are you naming classes with a `Class` suffix?

Comment: Well, for collections and deelgates it is recommended to add "Delegate" or "Collection" at the end. Then I thought why not to do that for Classes actually. But you are right. R# is not doing something odd it seems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well if you name your class Business you woudn't have that suffix :)

```
Business myBusiness = new Business();
```

and why are you suffixing your class with Class ??